# Input and Output program

Tags: java

I am trying to get this program to read an input file line by line and then print it to an output file, so for example:

Input file contains:

```
cookies
cake
ice cream
```

I want the output file to display this:

Line 1: cookies

Line 2: cake

Line 3: ice cream

I cannot figure out how to do this however, so any help will be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the input file: ");
        String name = in.next();
        FileReader file = new FileReader(name);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

        String text = "";
        String line = reader.readLine();



        while(line != null){
            text += line;
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        reader.close();




        System.out.print("Enter the output file: ");
        String out = in.next();

        FileWriter filew = new FileWriter(out);

        BufferedWriter buffw = new BufferedWriter(filew);
        buffw.write(text);
        buffw.close();
        System.out.print("File written!");
        in.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the Problem with your code?

Comment: As of right now it is printing the output as a single line and I want it as multiple lines like how I mentioned.

Comment: You are reading each line and concatening it to a String without any new line added. So it seems legit. `readLine` consume the end line character(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the loop like:

```
while(line != null){
    text += line;
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

`readLine` method would eat up the new line character and hence you don't see it in the output file. You need to append a new line character at the end like:

```
while(line != null){
    text += line;
    text += '\n';
    line = reader.readLine();        
}
```

I would suggest you using `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation like:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = ...
while ..
    stringBuilder.append(line);
    stringBuilder.append('\n');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the end of line character again, because `readLine()` removes it:

```
while(line != null){

        text += line;
        text +="\n";
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
```